# How can I save my current shown image when I click a imageview(button)?

Tags: android, image, save

I have an ImageView that shows 10 different images (you can swipe trough them)
I have Like and a Dislike button, 
I want to achieve the following:

When I click on the imageview(button) to save the current shown image in the sd card and to retrieve these saved images and display them in a different activity (in a gridview).

I've read allot of how people tried to fix it and they were usually able.
But my situation is a bit different due to the fact that the images that are being displayed are stacked on top of eachother, I can also swipe them.

I would greatfully appreciate some example code of how I should face this problem.

How I think I should face this:

```
> 1. Imageview imageView = (Imageview) findViewById(R.id.imgLike);
> 2. setOnClickListener for the imgLike (this is the imageview "like" button)
> 3. Save the image everytime the user "likes" the image and save it in the SD card
> 4. In the next Activity load the saved images from the SD card and display them in a gridview
```

I would hope to get some help with step 3 and 4. Please do point it out.

Am I thinking correct or am I missing something?

thnx in advance

EDIT.1

```
package com.example.sick.foodinspiration;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.tubesock.Base64;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.rk.lib.view.SwipeView;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        SwipeView.OnCardSwipedListener {

    private final static int CARDS_MAX_ELEMENTS = 5;

    private FrameLayout contentLayout;
    private SwipeView mSwipeView;
    private Firebase mRef;
    public ImageView imageview;

    private int[] meals =                 {
            R.drawable.gevulde_avocados_met_ei,
            R.drawable.pasta_met_spinazie_en_garnalen,
            R.drawable.griekse_aardappelen,
            R.drawable.pasta_met_spinazie_en_gorgonzolasaus,
            R.drawable.zalm_spinazie,
            R.drawable.pasta_bloemkoolsaus,
            R.drawable.paella,
            R.drawable.zweedseballen_salade,
            R.drawable.rode_curry_met_runderreepjes,
            R.drawable.tonijnburger};

    private int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_swipe_view_demo);
        contentLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.contentLayout);


        // Add the swipe view
        mSwipeView = new SwipeView(this, R.id.imgSwipeLike, R.id.imgSwipeNope,
                this);
        contentLayout.addView(mSwipeView);

        // Adding the cards initially with the maximum limits of cards.
        for (int i = 0; i < CARDS_MAX_ELEMENTS; i++) {
            addCard(i);
        }
    }

    /**
     * On clicked view.
     *
     * @param clickedView
     *            the clicked view
     */
    public void onClickedView(View clickedView) {
        switch (clickedView.getId()) {
            case R.id.imgDisLike: {
                mSwipeView.dislikeCard();
                break;
            }

            case R.id.imgLike: {

                imageview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                imageview.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bm=imageview.getDrawingCache();

                OutputStream fOut = null;
                Uri outputFileUri;
                try {
                    File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator + "folder_name" + File.separator);
                    root.mkdirs();
                    File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, "myPicName.jpg");
                    outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);
                    fOut = new FileOutputStream(sdImageMainDirectory);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error occured. Please try again later.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                try {
                    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
                    fOut.flush();
                    fOut.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
                mSwipeView.likeCard();
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLikes() {

        System.out.println("An Card removed");
        // Add a card if you needed after any previous card swiped
        addCard(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisLikes() {
        System.out.println("An Card removed");
        // Add a card if you needed after any previous card swiped
        addCard(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSingleTap() {

    }

    /**
     * Adds the card to the swipe.
     */

    private void addCard(int position) {
        final View cardView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
                R.layout.item_swipe_view, null);
        final ImageView imgMeals = (ImageView) cardView
                .findViewById(R.id.imgMeals);
        imgMeals.setImageResource(meals[count]);
        count++;
        if (count == meals.length) {
            count = 0;
        }
        // Add a card to the swipe view..
        mSwipeView.addCard(cardView, position);

        // Create OnClickListener for the CookBookActivity
        // Declare Button for the Cookbook
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, CookbookActivity.class));
            }
        });

        // Check Authentication
        mRef = new Firebase(com.example.sick.foodinspiration.Constants.FIREBASE_URL);
        if (mRef.getAuth() == null) {
            loadLoginView();
        }
    }

    private void loadLoginView() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

**UPDATE 16-6-2016**
Im back with an update,
I've managed to succesfully add an image in the gallery. I used to have a problem with the folder **NOT** being showed, but I fixed it with;

```
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { sdImageMainDirectory.getAbsolutePath() }, null, null);
```

So now the Image that im addressing, is being place in a new folder. 
So far so good, however
**Problem 2**
I'm getting 5 hardcoded images from the drawable folder and want to show them in CardView.(So stacked on top of eachother)
Then I want to save these images in the SD card when the like button is being pressed or the swipe function is being used.

**Relevant code for this problem**

```
private int[] meals =                 {
            R.drawable.a,
            R.drawable.b,
            R.drawable.c,
            R.drawable.d,
            R.drawable.e};

    private int count = 0;
```

**AND**

```
private void addCard(int position) {
    final View cardView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
            R.layout.item_swipe_view, null);
    final ImageView imgMeal = (ImageView) cardView
            .findViewById(R.id.imgMeals);
    imgMeal.setImageResource(meals[count]);
    count++;
    if (count == meals.length) {
        count = 0;
    }
    // Add a card to the swipe view..
    mSwipeView.addCard(cardView, position);
```

The way I think I should face this, is the following:

```
> so *meals* is already being initialized so I dont have to do this.
> I have to make an OnClickListener under the 
private void addCard(int position)
> Implement the code Neo was kind to share with us.
> Put Neo's code in the onClick (Like) function
> Make sure the code listens to "meals" because this is the final ImageView
```

I hope im looking at this problem correctly.
If anyone can help me with this problem I would kindly appreciate it!

And thnx Neo for your help so far!

Comment: Incomplete question. Please post your code to understand, from where you are getting the list of images in which form.

Comment: edited(not sure if this is what u mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
imageview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); //Add this line.
imageview.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bm=imageview.getDrawingCache();
```

To save it in a file:

```
OutputStream fOut = null;
    Uri outputFileUri;
    try {
         File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
          + File.separator + "folder_name" + File.separator);
         root.mkdirs();
         File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, "myPicName.jpg");
         outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);
         fOut = new FileOutputStream(sdImageMainDirectory);
    } catch (Exception e) {
         Toast.makeText(this, "Error occured. Please try again later.",
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    try {
        bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
    } catch (Exception e) 
}
```

And don't forget to add permission in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Hello Neo,

I've tried your method but I keep getting a NULL pointer.
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.buildDrawingCache()' on a null object reference.     
     
I've put everything in the on create, im not sure if that's okey?

Comment: I hope you are writting your code just after Imageview imageView = (Imageview) findViewById(R.id.imgLike); and you are using correct id R.id.imgLike. Please check and let me know, or if possible update your post with updated code and xml.

Comment: Hey I keep getting an error. I've updated my original post with my MainActivity and you can see that I placed your code in the case R.id.imgLike: 

Im not sure if this is correct

Comment: Put this line, before buildingDrawingCache
        imageview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
And it will start working like charm, I have also updated my post :)

Comment: Hey Neo,

Thnx for helping me so far, but I keep getting this error.
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference

I've updated my code with your last line. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: That  means your imageView is not initialised. Check your code and initialise using findViewById()  :)

Comment: Alright Neo I initialised it like this: ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgMeals);
How can I check my sd card on my emulator?

Comment: Yes you are missing the initialisation part in your code, let me know if need more help :)

Comment: How am I supposed to do this and where?

Comment: In onCreate you can initialize the imageView, after setContentView, and rest code will be run onClick, as per your requirements.

Comment: @The1whoshallnotbenamed, Hope your issue is resolved, please accept the best answer :)

Comment: I'm still trying to fix this problem, I've added everything you've commented except the initialisation in the "case R.id.imgLike". This handles the Likes function, but I keep getting JAVA.IO.EXCEPTION at fOut.flush();
                    fOut.close();

Comment: Hey,

I've updated the post (see problem 2) and I've accepted your anwser!
thnx for the help so far :)

Comment: Do I have to close this post or just leave it like this?

Comment: Acceptance answer is like closing post. So no need to take further steps, Still you can upvote :)